# Adding minimum combination requirements on password policy

Tags: c#, regex

I need some help acquiring the right RegEx of the requirements to apply on password policy:

> Match 3 out of 5 possible combinations of passwords that might contain minimum 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 1 number, 1 special character, 1 Unicode

Right now what I have is this combination

`^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d!@#$%^&*()<>,._\d\p{L}]{8,64}$`

How do I apply the minimum 3 out of 5 possible combinations in the expression?

Comment: If I understood your question, you want to identify how many regex/rules matched in a string. Is that right? If so, you can't, you need to run many  simple regex in a chain and test all of them. A regex will only tell you if that string matches or not.

Comment: This would be much easier to do without regex. What (if any) programming language are you using?

Comment: I'm using c# @41686d6564standsw.Palestine

Comment: yes, I want to identify if the password contains minimum 3 possible combination or not @btafarelo

Comment: you can't. You must to write many simple regex and test each one in a loop. Uppercase Regex OK, Numeric Regex Fail and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write a helper method to validate the password. Something like the following should suffice:

```
static bool ValidPassword(string input)
{
    // TODO: Consider replacing this local variable with a static instance to
    //       initialize it only once.
    var checks = new List<Func<string, bool>>();
    checks.Add(s => Regex.IsMatch(s, @"[A-Z]"));
    checks.Add(s => Regex.IsMatch(s, @"[a-z]"));
    checks.Add(s => s.Any(c => char.IsDigit(c)));
    checks.Add(s => Regex.IsMatch(s, @"[!@#$%^&*()<>,._]"));
    // Used this instead of char.IsDigit (or just "\p{L}" to prevent English letters from
    // passing two checks. This will match any Unicode letter excluding English letters.
    checks.Add(s => Regex.IsMatch(s, @"[\p{L}-[A-Za-z]]"));

    int validChecksCount = 0;
    foreach(var check in checks)
    {
        if (check(input)) validChecksCount++;
        if (validChecksCount == 3) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a complex regex just like yours to check a password policy.

To count the individual rules you will need to write specific regex and test each one against your password.

Uppercase Regex
Lowercase Regex
Numeric Regex
Special Regex

and count how many have passed at the end like 0/4 or 4/4.